# Liferay Spring MVC Portlet Lexicon 1.0 Toggles

Tags: java, liferay, spring-portlet-mvc, lexicon

I am trying to leverage the [Lexicon library toggles](https://lexiconcss.wedeploy.io/content/toggles/) within a Liferay Spring MVC Portlet. I am using the Spring command for their form tag. Which get my POJO class boolean property. I set this to true and "bind" the value to the input value tag but switch does not renders as "on".
JSP:

```
<label> 
            <input name="POJO boolean property" id="POJO boolean property" value="${POJO boolean property}" class="toggle-switch" type="checkbox"> 
             <span aria-hidden="true" class="toggle-switch-bar"> 
                <span class="toggle-switch-handle"> 
                  <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-ok toggle-switch-icon toggle-switch-icon-on">
                  </span>
                <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-remove toggle-switch-icon toggle-switch-icon-off">
                </span>
             </span></span> 
        </input>
    </label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value attribute for checkbox input does not determinate the checked status.

You have to bind che `checked` attribute.

Example: 

`<input name="POJO boolean property" id="POJO boolean property" value="1" class="toggle-switch" type="checkbox" ${POJO-boolean-property ? 'checked' : ''}>`

Look the input checkbox guide here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: makes total sense but that would not bind the actual value to my POJO property. right?

Comment: Yes, the bind will be ok. Look at `${POJO-boolean-property ? 'checked' : ''}`